# Access Jetty server inside Docker from host

Tags: docker, jetty, docker-compose

I've been trying to deploy a Jetty server using docker-compose, but I can't seem to make my app's port available from my host machine.

Here is my compose.yml:

```
version: '3.3'

networks:
  app-network:

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:alpine
    command: postgres -c hba_file=/etc/pg_hba.conf
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: ******
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ******
    volumes:
      - postgresVolume:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./pg_hba.conf:/etc/pg_hba.conf
    networks:
      app-network:
        aliases:
          - mydb

  app:
    build: .
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "7001:7001"
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - app-network

volumes:
  postgresVolume:
```

When I run:

```
docker-compose up --build
```

Everything starts fine. But I can't seem to access my api from my host:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"username":"user","password":"superPass"}' http://localhost:7001/user/ --trace-ascii ./dump
```

I get:

```
== Info:   Trying ::1...
== Info: TCP_NODELAY set
== Info: Connected to localhost (::1) port 7001 (#0)
=> Send header, 136 bytes (0x88)
0000: POST /user/ HTTP/1.1
0016: Host: localhost:7001
002c: User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
0045: Accept: */*
0052: Content-Type: application/json
0072: Content-Length: 42
0086:
=> Send data, 42 bytes (0x2a)
0000: {"username":"user","password":"superPass"}
== Info: upload completely sent off: 42 out of 42 bytes
== Info: Empty reply from server
== Info: Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

Running

```
iptables -t nat -L -n
```

gives:

```
Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
MASQUERADE  all  --  172.17.0.0/16        0.0.0.0/0
MASQUERADE  all  --  172.19.0.0/16        0.0.0.0/0
MASQUERADE  all  --  172.18.0.0/16        0.0.0.0/0
MASQUERADE  tcp  --  172.19.0.3           172.19.0.3           tcp 
dpt:7001

Chain DOCKER (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
DNAT       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:7001 to:172.19.0.3:7001
```

EDIT:

Running `nmap localhost`

```
Starting Nmap 7.60 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2018-02-08 12:09 CET
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.000055s latency).
Other addresses for localhost (not scanned): ::1
Not shown: 998 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
5432/tcp open  postgresql
7001/tcp open  afs3-callback

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.03 seconds
```

Which both seem ok to me.

```
docker-compose ps
```

Seems correct too:

```
      Name                     Command               State           Ports
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
app_1   java -server -Xms2g -Xmx2g ...   Up      0.0.0.0:7001->7001/tcp
db_1    docker-entrypoint.sh postg ...   Up      5432/tcp
```

My Jetty server seems to listen on the correct ip and port:

```
2018-02-07 18:47:34.379 [main] INFO  o.e.jetty.server.AbstractConnector - Started ServerConnector@62452cc9{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1, h2c]}{0.0.0.0:7001}
```

Does anyone have an idea of what I am doing wrong ? I'm running Arch Linux,

```
docker-compose version


docker-compose version 1.18.0, build unknown
docker-py version: 2.7.0
CPython version: 3.6.4
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.0g  2 Nov 2017
```

Thanks

Comment: based on the `curl` response the communication works OK, only the server dont know what to do with your request, are you sure your app is configured to accepts JSON? maybe you need some extra header. I think if you enter the container app and run the same command you ll get the same response, that could eliminate docker problem and you could focus on the app problem

Comment: Yes my app runs fine when I run it locally. That's what confuses me

Comment: I ran the exact same postman query in both cases, but it only works when ran locally

Comment: could you run the `curl` with `--verbose` and update question

Comment: Is the port open and available ? Can you try an nmap on localhost to see what's up ?

Comment: I updated with nmap. As for curl --verbose, it is already in the post (i used --trace-ascii)

Comment: Any chance you were/are running connman on arch?

Comment: @Andrew I think I was at the time. I re-installed my nux partition since then though, so that's just off the top of my head. Do you think that was the issue?

Comment: Possibly, I recently switched from NetworkManager to Connman on Arch (host) and started having this issue intermittently.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Alright so ... Jetty was the faulty one for me here. I wasn't expecting this, but just changing my HTTP server implementation to Netty solved the issue with no modification to my code or configuration.

Maybe I should notify Jetty of this ?